# Is there a way to keep cell format while creating document from spreadsheet data?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that I use to create a document (pdf) from the form submission (spreadsheet).  This script works well.  However, when one particular columns value(s) transfer to the document from the spreadsheet it does not keep the number format. I tired .setNumberFormat but it is very vague (in my opinion) for its use and I was not successful.

Example:  In my script below (Line 12) "var Length_ = row[4];" has a value of 9,651 (or any other number) which is shown in the spreadsheet as 9,651 but when it puts this value into my 'new' document it shows as 9651 with no comma seperating the thousands place.  Is there a way to keep this format so it shows up in my document as 9,651 not 9651?

```
function sendDocument() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
 var startRow = sheet.getLastRow();  // First row of data to process  
 var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process  // Fetch the range of cells  
 var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1,numRows,sheet.getLastColumn())  // Fetch values for  each row in the Range. Needs 4 parameters :start row, start column, number of rows, number of columns 
 var data = dataRange.getValues();  //returns a 2D array with 0 indexed values : data[0] is row nr 1 and data[0][0] is first cell in this first row
for (i in data) {    
 var row = data[i];    
 var ID_ = row[1];  // First column is index 0   
 var facility_name = row[2];       // Second column is index 1  
 var facility_type = row[3]; 
 var Length_ = row[4];
 var Acres_ = row[5]; 
 var Submission_Date = row[6];
 var email_address1 = row[7];
 var email_address2 = row[8];
// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
 var copyId   = DocsList.getFileById("162VlFMAMHad4i2FvuzSL5eAT98-j8SFx6TNXaiBe3DQ")
            .makeCopy("POD BBC Prickly Pear Contraction"+' for '+ID_)
            .getId();
// Open the temporary document
 var copyDoc  = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document’s body section
 var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();
// Replace place holder keys/tags,  
 copyBody.replaceText('keyID', ID_);
 copyBody.replaceText('keyFacilityName', facility_name);
 copyBody.replaceText('keyFacilityType', facility_type);
 copyBody.replaceText('keyLength', Length_);
 copyBody.replaceText('keyAcres', Acres_);
 copyBody.replaceText('keySubmissionDate', Submission_Date);
// Save and close the temporary document
 copyDoc.saveAndClose();
// Convert temporary document to PDF by using the getAs blob conversion
 var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");
  // Attach PDF and send the email
   var subject = "POD BBC Prickly Pear Contraction"+' for '+ID_;
   var body    = "Document for POD BBC Prickly Pear Contraction"+' for '+ID_+" has been created.  Please see attached PDF";
   MailApp.sendEmail(email_address1, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
   MailApp.sendEmail(email_address2, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
// Delete temp file
 DocsList.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(false);  
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to take care of formatting yourself, there are many ways to do that, I usually do it with strings manipulations because that's what I found easier.

Here is a small function that formats numbers with this fixed pattern `###,###.##`

```
function toFormatedNumbers(val){
  if(val==''){temp='';return temp}
  var temp = val.toString().replace(/[^\d\.-]/g,'').split('.');
  if(temp[0]==''){temp[0]='0'}
  if(temp.length==1){var result = temp[0]+'.00'}
  else{
  var int = temp[0]
  var dec = temp[1]
      if(dec.length==1){var result=int+'.'+dec+'0'}else{var result=int+'.'+dec}
  }
  var out=result;// result is in the form ######.##
  Logger.log(result.length)
  if(result.length>6){out=result.substring(0,result.indexOf('.')-3)+','+result.substring(result.indexOf('.')-3)}
  return out;// out has the comma separator for thousands
}
```

You can test it with the logger, it will return `34,567.40`

```
function test(){
Logger.log(toFormatedNumbers(34567.4))
}
```

Comment: @ Serge insas  Thank you for the quick response.  I am still a little unsure of where to use the script you provivded?  Since I only need the one column to stay formatted for my document, can I do that or will it format all ceels?  Also, where do I run this function?  Meaning, after I retrieve the data and before the copy of my document is made?  Or after the copy is made and somewhere in / before the .copyBody section of my script?  I'm sorry my inexperience has left me with questions.  I just started writing scripts this week.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries ;-) use it simply like this :  `var Length_ = toFormatedNumbers(row[4]);` for example, repeat for every variable that you need to format.